# Can someone explain how this JavaScript/Angular code works?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm reading through [John Papa's angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) and came across this code under the **Exception Handling** section. Can someone please explain to me where `reason` comes from or how it works in that code? This is one of those JavaScript/Angular things I just don't get how it works.

```
/* recommended */
angular
    .module('blocks.exception')
    .factory('exception', exception);

exception.$inject = ['logger'];

function exception(logger) {
    var service = {
        catcher: catcher
    };
    return service;

    function catcher(message) {
        return function(reason) {
            logger.error(message, reason);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `catcher` function returns a function itself that has the argument `reason`. In the code you posted, the function isn't called, therefore there is no `reason` provided, yet.

Assuming someone has injected exception somewhere else, you could call it like this:

```
var catcher = exception.catcher('This is a message');
var loggerError = catcher('This is the reason');
```

Or in a single line:

```
var loggerError = exception.catcher('This is a message')('This is the reason');
```

Comment: What is the advantage of doing it that way over `function catcher(message, reason)`?

Comment: You can preconfigure the logger. Think of `var log = exception.catcher('Something went wrong')` and the reason as the error in an `$http.get(...).then(successFn, function (error) { log(error); };`